# Replace text inside elements with text from other elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table:

```html
<table class="sales-shipments">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="shipment-customer-name">Customer Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00012962">replacetextSO-00012962</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00012909">replacetextSO-00012909</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00013031">replacetextSO-00013031</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00013002">replacetextSO-00013002</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00013032">replacetextSO-00013032</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I would like to replace the text that's inside the elements that has the class "replacetext" with the text that has the class "sourcetext" below:

```html
<div id="source-elements">
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00012962">Customer Name 1</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00012909">Customer Name 2</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00013031">Customer Name 3</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00013002">Customer Name 4</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00013032">Customer Name 5</div>
</div>
```

For example "replacetextSO-00012962" would be replaced with "Customer Name 1" taken from the div with the classes "sourcetext" and "SO-00012962" and this would be repeating for the remainer so that "replacetext" will always be replaced with "sourcetext" inside the column labelled "Customer Name".

Do you know you how this can be done in vanilla javascript?

Comment: Do you want to use html `div` as a database?!

Comment: Yes I do, this is outside my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through every `replacetext` and get the distinctive id (second class value of the element) and add `.sourcetext` at the begining of it and we have the class of source, get the text and replace.

Here is an example:

```js
function replace() {
  const replaces = document.querySelectorAll('.replacetext');
  const sources = document.querySelectorAll('.sourcetext');

  replaces.forEach(e => {
    const source = '.sourcetext.'+e.classList[1];
    e.innerText = document.querySelector(source).innerText;
  });
}

document.querySelector('#replace').addEventListener('click', replace);
```

```html
<button id="replace">Replace</button>

<table class="sales-shipments">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="shipment-customer-name">Customer Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00012962">replacetextSO-00012962</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00012909">replacetextSO-00012909</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00013031">replacetextSO-00013031</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00013002">replacetextSO-00013002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00013032">replacetextSO-00013032</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div id="source-elements">
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00012962">Customer Name 1</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00012909">Customer Name 2</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00013031">Customer Name 3</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00013002">Customer Name 4</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00013032">Customer Name 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really worked the way I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding we need to get value from `.sourcetext .text-id` and feed it to `.replacetext .text-id`
There are various way to achieve this and one of them is:

```js
function clickHandler() {
  const sourceTextElems = document.getElementById("source-elements").children;
  for (let i=0; i<sourceTextElems.length; i++) {
    const elemId = (sourceTextElems[i].className).replace("sourcetext ", "");
    const replaceElem = document.getElementsByClassName(`replacetext ${elemId}`);

    if (!!replaceElem.length){
      replaceElem[0].innerText = sourceTextElems[i].innerText;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#source-elements {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickHandler()">Replace</button>
<table class="sales-shipments">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="shipment-customer-name">Customer Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00012962">replacetextSO-00012962</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00012909">replacetextSO-00012909</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00013031">replacetextSO-00013031</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00013002">replacetextSO-00013002</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="replacetext SO-00013032">replacetextSO-00013032</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="source-elements">
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00012962">Customer Name 1</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00012909">Customer Name 2</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00013031">Customer Name 3</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00013002">Customer Name 4</div>
  <div class="sourcetext SO-00013032">Customer Name 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try if this works:**

```js
const sourceTexts = document.querySelector(".source-elements .sourcetext");
const replaceTexts = document.querySelector(".sales-shipments tbody tr td .replacetext");

sourceTexts.forEach((el, i) => {
  replaceText[i].innerText = el.innerText;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can perform it like this

```js
let targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.replacetext');
let sourceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.sourcetext');

Array.from(targetElements).map(element => {
  let classes = element.classList;
  Array.from(sourceElements).map(item => {
    if(item.classList.contains(classes[1])) {
      console.log('in');
      element.innerText = item.innerText;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<table class="sales-shipments">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="shipment-customer-name">Customer Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00012962">replacetextSO-00012962</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00012909">replacetextSO-00012909</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00013031">replacetextSO-00013031</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00013002">replacetextSO-00013002</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="replacetext SO-00013032">replacetextSO-00013032</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="source-elements">
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00012962">Customer Name 1</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00012909">Customer Name 2</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00013031">Customer Name 3</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00013002">Customer Name 4</div>
    <div class="sourcetext SO-00013032">Customer Name 5</div>
</div>
```

Start with getting all items with class `.replacetext` and `.sourcetext`. After that you check for each item in the first selection if you can find an Item with the `S0-*******` class if that is the case you can replace the `innerText`